# Change "srcset" to "data-srcset" in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to change the attribute "srcset" to "data-srcset" and "srt" to "data-srt" in Drupal 8 responsive images and i didn't find a solution in hours.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

:-) AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy `responsive-image.html.twig` file to your theme
2. Then use the `without` twig filter over the `{{ source_attributes }}`. [Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates).
3. Add `data-srcset="{{ source_attributes.srcset }}` to render the srcset in the attribute you choose, `data-srcset` in this case
4. Your modifications must look like this `<source{{ source_attributes|without('srcset') }} data-srcset="{{ source_attributes.srcset }}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution in THEME.theme

for normal images:

```
  function THEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes']['data-src'] = $variables['attributes']['src'];
    $variables['attributes']['src'] = '';
  }
```

and for responsive images:

```
  function THEME_preprocess_responsive_image(&$variables) {
    $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['data-srcset'] = $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['srcset'];
    $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['srcset'] = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The preprocess function in THEME.theme is the right way forward. Here's a refinement of the code posted so far:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_responsive_image().
 * @see core/themes/stable/templates/field/responsive-image.html.twig
 */

function THEME_preprocess_responsive_image(&$variables) {
  // Loop through the sources in case there's more than one source for this image
  foreach ($variables['sources'] as $source) {
    // Get the original srcset for each source
    $original_srcset = $source->offsetGet('srcset')->value();
    // Assign it to a new attribute called 'data-srcset'
    $source->offsetSet('data-srcset', $original_srcset);
    // Unset the original srcset
    $source->offsetSet('srcset', NULL);
  }
}
```